# Zip many files into several archives

Tags: linux, compression, zip

Running Linux. I have a directory of around 150 large CSV files; simply doing a `zip -9` on them results in a monolithic file that is still too large. I would like it to simply zip them in maybe four or five zip files of 30-40 CSVs each; this way sequencing or spanned zip order won't be a problem, as each zip is independent. There must be a simple way to do this. Any suggestions?

(and yes, zip is the preferred format, if possible)

Answer (score 23):

Isn't -s switch enough?
You may use zip -s  to split the file into files of  maximum size, e.g.:

"zip -s 300m <2 gb file>" produces:

```
file.zip (300 mb, master file)
file.001.zip (300 mb)
file.002.zip (300 mb)
file.003.zip (300 mb)
file.004.zip (300 mb)
file.005.zip (300 mb)
file.006.zip (200 mb)
```

Then "unzip file.zip" will unzip everything together.

Comment: What version of zip is this??  I get `file.z01 file.z02 ... file.zip` **and `unzip file.zip` does not work directly** (I would use zip -F to recombine them first).  Note these are not "independent" as requested.

Comment: @sourcejedi: In this answer (http://superuser.com/a/602736/195224) are some more detailed explanations.

Comment: @mpy I know, I've just written that answer :).

Comment: @sourcejedi: Oh yes, now you say it... `;)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` *on the list of input files* :-).

(Not tested, I've included rm commands for cleanup, take care).

```
ls *.csv > csvfiles
split -d -l30 - csvfiles < csvfiles
for i in csvfiles[0-9][0-9]; do
  zip "$i.zip" -@ < "$i"
done

rm csvfiles
rm csvfiles[0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: Why do you use `split -C` (`--line-bytes`) and not `split -l` (`--lines`)? That would be more predictable, with regard to how many CSV files are in one archive.

Comment: I skimmed the manpage too quickly.  Thanks, I'll fix it!